# How to get O(nlogn) from T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I want to calculate `O(n log(n))` without using the master theorem.

Does anyone know a mathematical way of calculating `O(n log(n))` from the  recursive formula `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)`?

Comment: Wild guess: Induction on n? However, I don't see what this has to do with "the algorithm" (whatever that is).

Comment: You can use the [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) instead of doing it all by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draw a recursion tree:

height of the tree will be log n

cost at each level will come out to be constant times n

Hence the total cost will be O(nlogn). http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/C455/html/notes/Chapter4/RecursionTree.htm

And you can always prove it by induction if you want.

Answer (score 22):

Notice the pattern (simplified a bit, better would be to keep `O(n)` rather than `n`):

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n
     = 2(2T(n/4) + n/2) + n  = 4T(n/4) + n + n  = 4T(n/4) + 2n
     = 4(2T(n/8) + n/4) + 2n = 8T(n/8) + n + 2n = 8T(n/8) + 3n
     = 8(2T(n/16) + n/8)+ 3n = 8T(n/16)+ n + 3n = 16T(n/16) + 4n
     ...                                        = 32T(n/32) + 5n
     ...
                                                = n*T(1) + log2(n)*n
                                                = O(n*log2(n))
```

Comment: (With thanks to user2076566 who made a technically correct edit to clarify what I was glossing over, but was rejected by three high-rating users.)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still figuring out how to draw the recursion tree:

Image : recursion tree for an T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n) algorithm

Drawing a tree as below we can see that each time we divide by two and going till our leaves are equal to 1

```
n/2^k = 1 
2^k = n 
k= log(n)
```

The above statements prove that our tree has a depth of **log(n)**.

At each level, we do an operation costing us O(n).

Even though we divide by two each time, we still do the operation on both parts so we have **n** iterations at each level.

Since we execute it a number of times equal to our depth, the resulting complexity is **O(nlog(n))**.

[image]

Also, check out this video tutorial https://youtu.be/1K9ebQJosvo